# How do I beat the giant nougat monster?

Tags: candy-box-2

I'm trying to get past the Giant Nougat monster in the castle but can't seem to get past him. Every time he one shots me. I've tried to teleport constantly while using the monkey wizard staff, and even got behind him but he still managed to kill me. How do I get past him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the boots and obsidian crown and enchanted monkey staff to fire loads of fireballs. Then when he came near me I teleported and jumped around!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to get the rocket boots from the desert fortress. Equip the obsidian crown and the monkey staff. Then just hold j to stay in the air until your fireballs kill him. No sweat

Comment: How do you get into the Desert Fortress though?

Comment: @John: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137323/how-do-i-get-to-the-desert-temple

Answer (score 5):

To beat him I used the octopus king crown with obsidian, the summoning tribal spear, and the boots of introspection. Just wait while you spawn minions. When there's enough minions between you and the monster, or when the monster wakes up, start shooting fireballs (having the red shark fin also helps).

Answer (score 5):

Get your magic upgraded at well using pain au chocolat a couple of time and then go attack him with no weapon equipped.    Put thorns shield everywhere and keep teleporting when you are near him, when you have put enough thorn shield wake him up with a fire ball and then teleport back he will go thru all the thorn shield and die.

Answer (score 2):

Obsidian Walls + Obsidian Crown + Black Demons + NO WEAPON (only attacks the obsidian walls anyway).

Answer (score 1):

U will need the black book of magic found in the hole to summon an obsidian wall and shoot from afar

My combo was boots on introspection (potion x) + obsidian wall + staff

Answer (score 0):

Get at  least 1556 health, which is what I did, then get pink enchanted gloves, octopus crown with jaspers, rocket boots and black demons spell

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scythe, run up to it, and just before you attack it, drink a berserker potion.

Answer (score 0):

You have a giant spoon of doom, use beserk potion, and black hole

Answer (score 0):

I used Obsidian Octopus King Thingamadoohickey and pink enchanted gloves with boots of introspection. He doesn't awaken until his health is at about 1,600 so you can hit him with fireballs until he's at about 1,700 (Octopi could wake him) Make sure you have no ranged weapons either. Try to get the octopi to build a tower to stand on, then use acid rain over and over (he stops when you're so far above him). Octopi will help you out as you acidinate him. Good luck, and may the Lollipops be with you!

Answer (score 0):

spam obsidian wall when he woke up, take introspection boots, take monkey staff enchanted and when its not a real problem, just reset the wall each time you can. your magic will to the job, plus he can't hurt you one poor time cause of the wall. easy.

edit: it works everytimes. just wait he woke up, set the wall when he is near you. spam the wall. the magic attack the nougat. even with the wall :D

re edit: it seems its just the fireball who goes on the monster.. take octopus crown enchanced (jaspers) who launch fireballs.

Ps: you can spam the fight for free candies! \o/

Answer (score 0):

I put on the staff, octopus crown with jaspers, knight's armour, pink enchanted gloves and the boots of introspection. I just kept teleporting around and occasionally used a fireball or black demon.

Answer (score 0):

The actual, simplest way, is to get the boots of introspection --which you can get by defeating yourself when you drink the x potion, and wear the normal octopus crown-- and have the enchanted tribal spear. Then just spam fire ball. You should also --if doing this technique-- have the enchanted red gloves and probably octopus crown with jaspers. This is basically the easiest way to defeat the naught monster and farm candies. That's what I do. It was super easy. HOPE YOU FIND THIS HELPFUL!

Answer (score 0):

use tribal spear and octopus crown with obsidian
then make sure a ton of octopuses are in front of you and then summon fireballs at him
I tried that and I did it first try
I hope it works for you

Answer (score -1):

If you have over 1000 health, the scythe and the enchanted knight armor you can just walk up to him and kill him.