# How do I get to the desert temple?

Tags: candy-box-2

How do I reach the desert temple in Candy Box 2?

I've already reached the castle, got the P and L stones and many other things.

Answer (score 6):

There is a key to the desert fortress hidden in one of the treasure boxes in the cave which you enter when jumping into the hole right to the castle.  You need to be able to jump and use the anti gravity potion to reach it.

Comment: SPOILER!! It is worth noting to get back out again you need to use teleport to get you back up.  Otherwise you will lose your stuff when you die

Comment: SPOILER!! is marked with >!

Comment: @elzaer Or rocket boots!

Comment: You just need jump and maybe ~400 HP.